# rolling mean for stock data differs in pandas dataframe when computed vectorized than when computed row by row in iteration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have stock data of which I want to calculate SMA for every candle of OHLCV values.
calculated values differ when in vectorized calculation than when computed row wise.

sample data with 20 rows:

> ```
>                         timestamp   close    high     low  oi    open  volume
>     6095  1995-01-02T00:00:00+0530  221.20  224.00  221.20   0  221.75   19300  
>     6096  1995-01-03T00:00:00+0530  220.20  222.50  220.00   0  222.00   21100  
>     6097  1995-01-04T00:00:00+0530  217.40  220.75  216.50   0  220.50   10950  
>     6098  1995-01-05T00:00:00+0530  214.40  217.00  214.25   0  217.00   20700  
>     6099  1995-01-06T00:00:00+0530  211.05  214.90  209.00   0  212.50   34850  
>     6100  1995-01-09T00:00:00+0530  205.10  209.00  203.00   0  203.00   22600  
>     6101  1995-01-10T00:00:00+0530  194.05  205.50  192.25   0  204.50   30400    
>     6102  1995-01-11T00:00:00+0530  201.60  205.00  189.00   0  189.00   16900  
>     6103  1995-01-12T00:00:00+0530  195.00  201.00  192.75   0  201.00   20750  
>     6104  1995-01-13T00:00:00+0530  197.30  199.95  194.50   0  194.50    5400  
>     6105  1995-01-16T00:00:00+0530  194.00  202.00  193.00   0  201.00   10300  
>     6106  1995-01-17T00:00:00+0530  192.60  194.00  191.50   0  193.25   24100  
>     6107  1995-01-18T00:00:00+0530  194.95  195.00  192.05   0  192.25    4400  
>     6108  1995-01-19T00:00:00+0530  195.10  197.50  194.00   0  194.00   17900  
>     6109  1995-01-20T00:00:00+0530  185.20  196.50  185.00   0  195.60   16250  
>     6110  1995-01-23T00:00:00+0530  175.25  185.00  173.00   0  185.00   10700  
>     6111  1995-01-24T00:00:00+0530  176.20  180.00  165.00   0  173.25   16750  
>     6112  1995-01-25T00:00:00+0530  175.30  178.25  173.00   0  174.50   21550  
>     6113  1995-01-27T00:00:00+0530  184.10  186.50  176.00   0  176.50   10400  
>     6114  1995-01-30T00:00:00+0530  182.95  184.00  172.50   0  172.50   34200
> ```

```
d20['sma'] = d20.rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean()['close']
```

> ```
>                          timestamp   close    high     low  oi    open  volume     sma
>     6095  1995-01-02T00:00:00+0530  221.20  224.00  221.20   0  221.75   19300  221.20
>     6096  1995-01-03T00:00:00+0530  220.20  222.50  220.00   0  222.00   21100  220.70
>     6097  1995-01-04T00:00:00+0530  217.40  220.75  216.50   0  220.50   10950  219.60
>     6098  1995-01-05T00:00:00+0530  214.40  217.00  214.25   0  217.00   20700  218.30
>     6099  1995-01-06T00:00:00+0530  211.05  214.90  209.00   0  212.50   34850  216.85
>     6100  1995-01-09T00:00:00+0530  205.10  209.00  203.00   0  203.00   22600  213.63
>     6101  1995-01-10T00:00:00+0530  194.05  205.50  192.25   0  204.50   30400  208.40
>     6102  1995-01-11T00:00:00+0530  201.60  205.00  189.00   0  189.00   16900  205.24
>     6103  1995-01-12T00:00:00+0530  195.00  201.00  192.75   0  201.00   20750  201.36
>     6104  1995-01-13T00:00:00+0530  197.30  199.95  194.50   0  194.50    5400  198.61
>     6105  1995-01-16T00:00:00+0530  194.00  202.00  193.00   0  201.00   10300  196.39
>     6106  1995-01-17T00:00:00+0530  192.60  194.00  191.50   0  193.25   24100  196.10
>     6107  1995-01-18T00:00:00+0530  194.95  195.00  192.05   0  192.25    4400  194.77
>     6108  1995-01-19T00:00:00+0530  195.10  197.50  194.00   0  194.00   17900  194.79
>     6109  1995-01-20T00:00:00+0530  185.20  196.50  185.00   0  195.60   16250  192.37
>     6110  1995-01-23T00:00:00+0530  175.25  185.00  173.00   0  185.00   10700  188.62
>     6111  1995-01-24T00:00:00+0530  176.20  180.00  165.00   0  173.25   16750  185.34
>     6112  1995-01-25T00:00:00+0530  175.30  178.25  173.00   0  174.50   21550  181.41
>     6113  1995-01-27T00:00:00+0530  184.10  186.50  176.00   0  176.50   10400  179.21
>     6114  1995-01-30T00:00:00+0530  182.95  184.00  172.50   0  172.50   34200  178.76
> ```

```
d10 = data[:10] 
d10['sma'] = d10.rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean()['close']
```

> ```
>                       timestamp   close    high     low  oi    open  volume     sma
>     6095  1995-01-02T00:00:00+0530  221.20  224.00  221.20   0  221.75   19300  221.20
>     6096  1995-01-03T00:00:00+0530  220.20  222.50  220.00   0  222.00   21100  220.70
>     6097  1995-01-04T00:00:00+0530  217.40  220.75  216.50   0  220.50   10950  219.60
>     6098  1995-01-05T00:00:00+0530  214.40  217.00  214.25   0  217.00   20700  218.30
>     6099  1995-01-06T00:00:00+0530  211.05  214.90  209.00   0  212.50   34850  216.85
>     6100  1995-01-09T00:00:00+0530  205.10  209.00  203.00   0  203.00   22600  213.63
>     6101  1995-01-10T00:00:00+0530  194.05  205.50  192.25   0  204.50   30400  208.40
>     6102  1995-01-11T00:00:00+0530  201.60  205.00  189.00   0  189.00   16900  205.24
>     6103  1995-01-12T00:00:00+0530  195.00  201.00  192.75   0  201.00   20750  201.36
>     6104  1995-01-13T00:00:00+0530  197.30  199.95  194.50   0  194.50    5400  198.61
> ```

```
d5 = data[11:16] 
d15 = pd.concat([d10,d5]) 
d15['sma'] = d15.rolling(5, min_periods=1).mean()['close']
```

> ```
>                          timestamp   close    high     low  oi    open  volume     sma
>     6095  1995-01-02T00:00:00+0530  221.20  224.00  221.20   0  221.75   19300  221.20
>     6096  1995-01-03T00:00:00+0530  220.20  222.50  220.00   0  222.00   21100  220.70
>     6097  1995-01-04T00:00:00+0530  217.40  220.75  216.50   0  220.50   10950  219.60
>     6098  1995-01-05T00:00:00+0530  214.40  217.00  214.25   0  217.00   20700  218.30
>     6099  1995-01-06T00:00:00+0530  211.05  214.90  209.00   0  212.50   34850  216.85
>     6100  1995-01-09T00:00:00+0530  205.10  209.00  203.00   0  203.00   22600  213.63
>     6101  1995-01-10T00:00:00+0530  194.05  205.50  192.25   0  204.50   30400  208.40
>     6102  1995-01-11T00:00:00+0530  201.60  205.00  189.00   0  189.00   16900  205.24
>     6103  1995-01-12T00:00:00+0530  195.00  201.00  192.75   0  201.00   20750  201.36
>     6104  1995-01-13T00:00:00+0530  197.30  199.95  194.50   0  194.50    5400  198.61
>
>     6106  1995-01-17T00:00:00+0530  192.60  194.00  191.50   0  193.25   24100  196.11
>     6107  1995-01-18T00:00:00+0530  194.95  195.00  192.05   0  192.25    4400  196.29
>     6108  1995-01-19T00:00:00+0530  195.10  197.50  194.00   0  194.00   17900  194.99
>     6109  1995-01-20T00:00:00+0530  185.20  196.50  185.00   0  195.60   16250  193.03
>     6110  1995-01-23T00:00:00+0530  175.25  185.00  173.00   0  185.00   10700  188.62
> ```

values of sma differs for same rows in d15 and d20 for last 5 rows
Which calculations of sma is accurate 1) vectorized or 2) iterative row wise
I am trying to compute SMA after adding new rows into dataframe.